# Where should I configure the jobs to build the project and to deploy it?

Tags: jenkins, virtualbox, devops

I am very new to devops and I could really use some help to understand the concept of this.

So I am trying to develop a continuous integration environment using VirtualBox and Vagrant. I've read some examples of how to build such an environment to pull a maven project from github, build it and deploy to the nexus artefact repository.

I have managed to configure a VM with Ubuntu and installed Tomcat on it.

What I don't understand is where should I configure the Jenkins jobs to build the project and to deploy it to nexus and to make it run in Tomcat Server. On my local machine or in the virtual machine ?

Thanks.

Comment: The devops tag is for programming questions about DevOps ("development" and "operations"), which is a software development method that stresses communication, collaboration, integration, automation, and measurement of cooperation between software developers and other IT professionals. Non-programming related questions should be asked on the DevOps Stack Exchange site. View devops tag

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bridged/hostonly networking for ubuntu, then you can run the jenkins in your host machine. If it is NAT/Private networking, use guest machine to run jenkin jobs.